# How to not accept decimal and letter as input

Tags: c++

What i need is the absolute way to not accept decimals or if there is a function that will not accept both decimals and letters

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>


using namespace std;

double checkInput(double pagkain)
{
    do
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        if (floor(pagkain) != pagkain || pagkain >= 51)
        {
            cout << "Invalid Input, We do not aceept letters or decimals. \nPlease try again: ";
        }

    }while (floor(pagkain) != pagkain || (pagkain >50));

    return pagkain;
}
```

Comment: Please don't paste your entire program, especially when it really has nothing to do with your core question. Also, this isn't a code review site. It's for asking very specific programming questions.

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas Thank you for reminding me, appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you only expect integers, it's safe to change the data types to `int` instead of `double`.

Next, you can read it as a string and verify its correctness.

You can do something like that:

```
int GetValidInteger(int lowerBound, int upperBound){
  string result;
  while(true){
    getline(cin, result);
    bool valid = true;
    for(int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++){
      if(!isdigit(result[i])){
        valid = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if(!valid){
      cout << "Only integers are accepted. Try again...\n";
      continue;
    }
    int intResult = stoi(result);
    // Outside this loop, you know that you have a valid integer.
    // You can check now for your other constraints.
    if(intResult < lowerBound || intResult > upperBound)
      cout << "Input should be between " << lowerBound << " and " << upperBound << ". Try again...\n";
    else
      return intResult;
  }
}
```

You can use that function to get valid inputs in the desired ranges. To get the order in the 1-5 range, you do that:

`int order = GetValidInteger(1,5);`

Same when you want the input in 1-50 range.

Comment: Woahh! Awesome man! This is what i've been looking for :o Thank You! btw how can i learn about the stoi?

Comment: You're welcome! Here's a reference http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol